# Equation representing the branch of hyperbola

Tags: curves

Is there an equation representing the one branch of hyperbola ($x^2-y^2=1$).

This is the regular hyperbola:

[image]

This is the expected curve:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to "exclude" possible negative $x$ we can do the trick of taking the square root, since this is not possible for negative numbers, then cancel the square root by using a square. Thus the equation will be identical as the one above, but only defined on the positive numbers for $x$.

$$(\sqrt x^2)^2 - y^2 = 1$$

Note that we could in a similar way get only the "left" part of the curve, with negative $x$ values, by putting a minus sign on $x$, i.e.

$$(\sqrt{ -x}^2)^2 - y^2 = 1$$

Comment: nice trick! I will think about algebraic generalization of this.